# Java8 FP if/else if/else replace by lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I have a problem with Java 8 if statements. Can someone show me a way to write this code without if's using only Java 8 lambdas?
The solution shouldn't have if's, while's or for's. Is it even possible?

```
if (first_number == second_number) {
  return "PERFECT";
} else if (first_number > second_number) {
  return "ABUNDANT";
} else {
  return "DEFICIENT";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution with lambdas? I'm assuming integer values, but shouldn't be too hard to switch to float or double.

```
    int first_number = 10;
    int second_number = 20;
    IntBinaryOperator subtract = (n1, n2) -> n1 - n2; // Subtract second from first value
    IntUnaryOperator determineSign = n -> Integer.signum(n); // Determine the sign of the subtraction
    IntFunction<String> message = key -> { // Sign of 0 means value has been 0 (first_number == second_number). Sign of 1 = positive value, hence equals first_number > second_number, otherwise return the default.
        Map<Integer, String> messages = new HashMap<>();
        messages.put(0, "PERFECT");
        messages.put(1, "ABUNDANT");
        return messages.getOrDefault(key, "DEFICIENT");
    };

     return message.apply(determineSign.applyAsInt(subtract.applyAsInt(first_number, second_number)));
```

Edit: Andreas mentioned valid concerns, I agree you wouldn't do it like that. But I think its more about proving that it is possible using lambdas. :) Another method (ab)using Optional:

```
    int first_number = 20;
    int second_number = 20;

    Optional<Integer> dummy = Optional.of(0); // Dummy allowing to call filter on the Optional
    Predicate<Integer>isAbundant = i -> first_number > second_number; // Check if input is abundant
    Predicate<Integer> isPerfect = i -> first_number == second_number; // Check if input is perfect
    Supplier<String> other = () -> dummy.filter(isAbundant).map(i -> "ABUNDANT").orElse("DEFICIENT"); // Fallback, if input is not perfect. Check for abundant or return default
    Supplier<String> validate = () -> dummy.filter(isPerfect).map(i -> "PERFECT").orElse(other.get()); // Check if input is perfect or use fallback

    return validate.get();
```

Comment: ***Warning:*** `n1 - n2` may overflow and produce incorrect result.

Comment: Creating a `Map` and boxing a `signum` value just to pick one of 3 strings is very inefficient, both space- and performance-wise.

Comment: @Andreas plus all that noise by unnecessarily creating all these functions. If we really want to go into the direction of providing the constants as collection, it would be as simple as `return List.of("DEFICIENT", "PERFECT", "ABUNDANT") .get(1 + Integer.signum(Integer.compare(first_number, second_number)));`

Comment: @Holger: It requires Java 9 though and the question stated Java 8. Nevertheless I like the Java 9 way. :)

Comment: There is no problem replacing `List.of` with `Arrays.asList`…

Answer (score 7):

No "if's, while's or for's", but no lambdas either:

```
return (first_number == second_number ? "PERFECT" :
        first_number > second_number ? "ABUNDANT" : "DEFICIENT");
```

The `? :` is called the **conditional operator** in the Java Language Specification (see [15.25. Conditional Operator `? :`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)), but is commonly known as the **ternary operator**, since it is the only operator in Java with 3 parts.